# Convert mysql query to Query Builder laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to convert mysql it to laravel code

```
SELECT *,AVG(number_star) FROM rates GROUP BY user_be_rate_id
```

I tried but they didn't work

```
Rate::all()->groupBy('user_be_rate_id')->avg('number_star');
or
Rate::->avg('number_star')->groupBy('user_be_rate_id');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `selectRaw` or `select(DB::raw())` like this:

```php
Rate::groupBy('user_be_rate_id')->selectRaw('*, AVG(number_star')->get();
```

```php
Rate::groupBy('user_be_rate_id')->select('*', DB::raw('AVG(number_star)')->get();
```